# How to post form data in a nodejs application with routes?

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms, express, routes

I tried to build a simple node application with routes, but it gives a 404 network error as it's unable to post. Can someone please point out my mistake and correct it?

First I created a directory sampProj, then in it, I've a file - **appl.js** and a directory **routes**. Inside **routes** directory, I've a directory **routes** and a file **main.js**. Again inside mainCode directory, I've 3 files - main.js, server.js and index.html.

Sorry for the complicated directions, I wanted to test out small and then start building on it. I want to mention that this code with just server.js and index.html worked without the routes, i.e server.js uses app.post and app.get etc. instead of the corresponding router methods which I've shown below.

So here's the code for the application:

appl.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = module.exports.app = express();

// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false}));

// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Adding routes
var server = require(__dirname + '/routes/main');
var mainCode = require(__dirname + '/routes/mainCode/main.js');

app.use('/Service', server);
app.use('/Service/mainCode', mainCode);

// Catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('Not Found');
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
});

/* Error Handlers */
// It will print the Stacktrace of error
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.send({
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

app.listen(3000,function(){
    console.log("Working on port 3000");
});
```

routes/main.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.send('<code>Welcome to Service</code>');
});

module.exports = router;
```

mainCode/main.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var server = require(__dirname + '/server');
router.use('/server', server);
module.exports = router;
```

mainCode/index.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Form Data</title>
 </head>
  <body>
      <form id="uploadForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/" method="post">
      <input id = "userPhotos" type="file" name="userPhotos" multiple />
      <input type='text' id='random' name='random'><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="submit">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

mainCode/server.js:

```
var express =   require("express");
var router = express.Router();
var multer  =   require('multer');

var storage =   multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, './uploads/');
  },
  filename: function (req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, file.fieldname + '-' + file.originalname);
  }
});

var upload = multer({ storage : storage }).any();

router.get('/',function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});

router.post('/',function(req,res){
    console.log("posted");
    console.log("posted");
    console.log(req.body);
    upload(req,res,function(err) {
    if(err) {
        console.error(err);
        return res.end("Error uploading file.");
    }
    console.log(req.body);
    console.log(req.files);
    res.end("File is uploaded");
});
});

module.exports = router;
```

Once I open localhost:3000/Service/mainCode/server in a browser, a form is displayed with one text input, but if I submit data, it's redirecting to localhost:3000 with error 404 displayed on the screen.

If you downvote this, please tell me why you're doing so, and in what way I can improve the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You access the form via the URL:

```
http://localhost:3000/Service/mainCode/server
```

right? 
In your `mainCode/server.js` you set the `get` as well as the `post` handling for the same URL.
So why do you call the root directory in `mainCode/index.html` on form submit:

```
 <form id="uploadForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/" method="post">
```

it should be:

```
<form id="uploadForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/Service/mainCode/server" method="post">
```

as far as I understand.
Usually if you want to send a formular to the same URL you would just leave the action attribute out like:

```
<form id="uploadForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
```

**EDIT:** Turned out that it solved the problem for the OP combined with the removing of the attribute `enctype`, which leads to the default `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` method.

But as the OP wanted to submit a file in the first place, he had to exchange the `body-parser` module with `multer` and set the `enctype` to `multipart/form-data` again.

Documentation of multer:
https://github.com/expressjs/multer

Comment: it's logging posted, but the req.body is printing - {}

Comment: you could try: app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
instead of passing false in your appl.js

Comment: also you can try to remove the enctype attribute on your client code like:
<form id="uploadForm" method="post">

Comment: yea, I kept it when I was trying to upload files, but removed it later to see if it'll atleast work for normal text input

Comment: yea, it worked after i changed enctype to application/x-www-form-urlencoded, extended: true wasn't needed

Comment: when i add a file input with multi-part enctype, it's giving 500 error on submission

Comment: if you want to send files keep it at multipart/form-data and set the body-parser to extended: true

Comment: still the same problem, now req.body too prints {}

Comment: and you restarted your server?

Comment: yea, i did restart

Comment: ok I think for uploading files you need something different:
https://github.com/expressjs/multer instead of body-parser

Comment: seems to be working after changing enctype and form action path. Thanks!